# Migrating svn subfolder from multiple branches to different git branches

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control, git-svn

I am facing a problem migrating subfolders in an svn branch to a git branch with its history my hierarchy looks something like this:

```
/temp
    /project1
        trunk/
        branches/
            /subfolder1
                /subfolder1.1
                    /want-to-migrate-folder
                /subfolder1.2
                    /same-want-to-migrate-folder
            /subfolder2
        tags/
    /project2
    /project3
```

I tried using this command:

git svn clone --branches=/subfolder1.1/want-to-migrate-folder --authors-file=authors.txt path/to/svn/repo/project1/branches/subfolder1 git-repo-name

But I ended up with a branch for every subfolder in the "want-to-migrate-folder"
and what i expected is the whole "want-to-migrate-folder" to be there and change when i switch branches according to each branch configuration.

I've been looking online but I couldn't manage to find an appropriate configuration to allow me to do so, any suggestions?

Comment: Please, can you clarify how you want the git repo to look like

Comment: I want to be able to make a branch for every subfolderx.x which only contains want-to-migrate-folder dont want to take the rest in the subfolderx.x

Comment: should trunk be exported to `master`?